# useEffect does not trigger render

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to change an array in useEffect hook, but it's not re rendering the DOM. I have an object with id/object as key/value, and I am trying to add those elements into `items` array, with `blankItem` as 2nd if there are any items. Now, if i console log the items, it works fine, but it doesn't render items correctly, always renders just blank item. Maybe i am using `useRef` hook wrong, any advice?

```
const items = useRef([]);
const itemsById = useSelector(itemsByIdSelector);
console.log(items) // works fine, logs {current: [...]}, proper array that i need to render.

useEffect(() => {
    const blankItem = {
        isBlank: true,
        title: 'Blank Page',
        id: 'blank',
    };
    items.current = Object.values(itemsById).map(item => item);

    if (items.current.length > 0) {
        items.current.splice(1, 0, blankItem);
    } else {
        items.current.push(blankItem);
    }

}, [items, itemsById]);
```

Rendering item (function returns this div):

```
<div>
    { items.current.map(item => {
        return (
            <Item item={ item }
                  key={ item.itemId }
            />
        );
     }) }
</div>
```

Comment: could you try useState hook instead of useRef? useRef is best suitable for dom object.

Comment: Substitute ref by state and you'll get your rerender. Changes in ref do not trigger a rerender in React.

Comment: @SametKaraca, yeah I was going to ask OP where was his `useState`. Ditto what @Konstantin said as well.